# How to create many functions in one table lua? (Corona SDK)

Tags: lua, coronasdk, lua-table

I'm trying to create ncar table with 2 different functions: setup ans main_frame

```
local ncar=
{
    img=display.newImageRect("test_car.png",50,120,true);
    x=0;
    y=0;
    frames=0;
    setup=function(self)
        return self;
    end
    main_frame=function(self)
        self.frames=self.frames+1;
        return function(event)
            self.img.x=self.x;
            self.img.y=self.y;
        end
    end

}
```

But compiler says that he expects to see '}' where the second function (main_frame in this case) starts, when I add it. What are the reasons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A comma or semicolon is required after `setup` function definition.
This is because you are creating a table by listing its fields, that should be separated from each other.

Comment: Crazy, I did not know Lua allowed a semicolon as field separator +1